# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine in VS2010 Only

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. I am getting this in visual studio only after upgrading from 32bit office 2013 to 64bit office 16. I have already installed the 64bit database engine and my published project from IIS is working with the existing access database. I switched debug mode to x64 and remove the references to the old office and replaced them with the new office access. How can I get Visual Studio 2010 to recognize my access database created in access 2013?

Things I have tried:

Installing Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable 64bit version.

Updating the office references in the project.

Debugging in x64 mode

Answer (score 0):

This is a little outside of my normal area of database application design;

it's unclear - you state 2016 Office 64 bit installed but then Access 2010 Redistributable/Runtime 64bit  - - so do you have a full license of Access installed?

if you do have the full Access license - try something that is quick: create a brand new database and import that table.  Then try the link to this new db.

Comment: Yes full license for Office 2016.  to be clear the issue is only within Visual Studio.  If I try and import any database it throws the error "'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine".  If that were true the project should not work from the published version of this asp.net website in IIS correct?  I cannot import a new access database to test with due to this error

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue in the past.
install [2007 Office System Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734) and restart visual studio.

Comment: I have heard that comment before but why the 2007 version when my access is 2016 64-bit?  And again I am still confused by why this project works in IIS.  Does IIS not have to use the same data source?

Comment: That question should be answered by Microsoft, i dont know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt many time with this problem, the solution was ever install one of these:

AccessDatabaseEngine 2007.exe
AccessDatabaseEngine_2010.exe
AccessDatabaseEngine_2016.exe
AccessDatabaseEngine_X64_2010.exe
AccessDatabaseEngine_X64_2016.exe

Most of the time I've solved installing the 2007 one even using 2016 version.

Answer (score 0):

To run 32-bit applications on IIS, you will get the same error. So, from the IIS 7, right-click on the applications' application pool and go to "advanced settings" and change "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to "TRUE".

Restart your website and it should work.

[image]